# Using ActionMailer RoR templates with Sendgrid API v3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sendgrid-api-v3

I've intergrated the sendgrid-ruby gem on my rails app and am trying to send an email I used to have sent via ActionMailer. I've used the example from sendgrid:

```
from = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com', name: 'Test Sender')
to = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com')
subject = 'This is a sendgrid test email'
content = Content.new(type: 'text/plain', value: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Ruby')
mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)

sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'])
response = sg.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
```

However, I'd like to replace the content with my old Mailer Templates I used in Rails. Is this possible?

Comment: How can you use a Mailer Template with sg.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)?

Comment: @slindsey3000 that is what I was trying to figure out if it was possible. I ended up using SMTP as discussed below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use their SMTP API which allows you to define or use your email templates in your rails app.

example [send guild ruby](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html)

Comment: thanks for clarifying. Do you know if there's a way to do it via their web api or is that bad practice?

Comment: it is not a bad practice as far as I know. Their web api allows you to use templates on a hosted service like (Mandril) on the other hand with their SMTP you can use your existing templates